# Calling a method using dynamic with an out parameter

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a `Dictionary<string,K>` where K is a type that is loaded through reflection, I can't name K.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how I'm supposed to use the `TryGetValue` method. I tried a couple of different things and they all lead to exceptions. What am I suppose to do?

```
dynamic dict = GetDictThroughMagic();
dynamic d;
bool hasValue = dict.TryGetValue("name",out d);
bool hasValue = dict.TryGetValue("name",d);
```

I can write the more verbose `if(dict.Contains("name")) d=dict["name"]`

But I'd prefer if I could write the more concise TryGetValue approach.

Updated to include actual exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The
best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,K>
.TryGetValue(string, out K)' has some invalid arguments
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Object& )
```

Comment: If you don't know what `K` is anyway, why not just use `IDictionary<string, object>` instead?  It will let you store objects of type `K` just fine and your method in the question would work.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, because in .Net, variables used as `ref` and `out` parameters must match the type exactly. And a `dynamic` variable is actually an `object` variable at runtime.

But you could work around that by switching which parameter is `out` and which is the return value, although working with that would be less nice than normal `TryGetValue()`:

```
static class DictionaryHelper
{
    public static TValue TryGetValue<TKey, TValue>(
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey value, out bool found)
    {
        TValue result;
        found = dict.TryGetValue(value, out result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
dynamic dict = GetDictThroughMagic();
bool hasValue;
dynamic d = DictionaryHelper.TryGetValue(dict, "name", out hasValue);
```

Comment: hmm for some reason I was hoping that dynamic would just kind of resolve this issue for me. I realize now why Ironpython turns your TryGetValue into a method that returns a tuple now.

Comment: Yeah, returning a `Tuple` would work too. `dynamic` is not magic, it mostly obeys the same rules as normal C#, except they are resolved at runtime, not compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a `dynamic`? Is this coming via an interop? I would suggest using a common abstraction that can be used here. Reflection does not mean dynamic, and this keyword is being thrown around in a static language in places that it is not needed. It was designed for interops...

More specific to your question: [Here is what seems like a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929444/dynamic-type-in-method-parameter). I do not believe that the cast can work here because it cannot cast up to type K.

Comment: I was trying an approach to make the code less ugly. Types are generated based on an xml doc at runtime. Once I have a `K` using dynamic is perfect. It's getting them out in the open that's the hard part.

Comment: @MichaelB I still say that this is a bit of a hack for a design that needs refactored, but I updated my answer to a link to another SO question. Basically, you cannot cast up using dynamics...it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the similar error but came to a solution making all access to the dictionary dynamic.

Try

```
dynamic dict = GetDictThroughMagic();
dynamic value = "wacka wacka"; // I renamed from 'd' and gave it a value
dynamic key = "name";

if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
{
    dict[key] = value;
}
```

Hope this works out for you!