# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException when using a dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, dynamic

In order to use any version of an API, I am choosing the DLL at runtime. In this DLL (ExternalDLL), there is  a class like this one:

```
public class NameClass
{
    private string firstN;
    private string lastN;

    public NameClass(string firstN, string lastN)
    {
        this.firstN = firstN;
        this.lastN = lastN;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private List<NameClass> listN = new List<NameClass>();
    public int CurrentIndex;

    public void GetName(out NameClass nclass)
    {
        if (CurrentIndex > -1 && CurrentIndex < listN.Count) nclass = listN[CurrentIndex];
        else nclass = null;
    }

}
```

So, the exception is raised when I try to use the method GetName()

```
dynamic myClass = Activator.CreateInstance("ExternalDLL.MyClass");
dynamic nameClass = Activator.CreateInstance("ExternalDLL.NameClass");
myClass.GetName(out nameClass);
```

When the method is called I get the RuntimeBinderException with this information:

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=A melhor correspondência de método sobrecarregado 'Tekla.Structures.Model.ModelObject.GetPhase(out Tekla.Structures.Model.Phase)' tem alguns argumentos inválidos

Comment: 1) Can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing the definitions of `MyClass` and `NameClass` in the external DLL?  2) Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the `RuntimeBinderException` including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception if any?  As it is there may not be enough detail for somebody to be able to answer your question.

Comment: I have improved as you asked... please check it out and let me know if is it ok...

Comment: Do these answer your question?  [Calling a method using dynamic with an out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10021265) and [Dynamic type in method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929538/3744182).

Comment: according to these links, what I was trying to do it is not possible

Comment: Not directly via `dynamic`.  You'll need to use a more traditional reflection approach.